# Is it safe to use 16kHz sample rate when recording raw PCM data?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, microphone

Documentation for Microphone.rate says that "Acceptable values are 5, 8, 11, 22, and 44." [1]. No 16kHz mentioned.

Hovewer, in the documentation for Microphone.codec [2] is said that "If you use the Speex codec, the sample rate is set to 16 kHz.".

If my microphone isn't connected to NetStream object, what I'll get after recording is just raw PCM data (not compressed by Nellymoser/Speex).

I tried to set mic.rate = 16 and it works just fine, although 16kHz isn't mentioned in Microphone.rate docs.

Is this OK to use mic.rate = 16 for raw PCM?

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#rate

[2] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#codec

P.S. I assume that "mic.rate = 16" means exactly 16000 samples per second. But who knows.

Comment: Who knows is right! If `mic.rate=11` means 11,025 samples/sec, I wonder what the "unacceptable" (according to docs) values mean. Part of the issue is that it also depends on the rates your sound capture device supports. I think your best bet is to confirm that it works on your target devices/environments and then have a beer :)

Comment: It seems to be exactly 16000. From speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual.pdf: "Sampling rate values of 8000, 16000 or 32000 Hz MUST be used. Any other sampling rates MUST NOT be used."